# Using /etc/passwd with NFS on Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, nfs, vmware-esxi

I'm trying to set up an NFS share on a server 2008 machine, that can be accessed from and ESXi server. However, when asked to provide a list of groups/accounts, the only two options I am given are AD Intergration, and a Username Mapping Server, neither of which I have.

A guide I was looking at used the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files, with Windows Services for Unix 3.5, but this isn't compatible with Windows Server 2008 64bit. Is it possible to do this Windows Server 2008, using just the two files, or will I have to use a third party NFS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They removed that feature in w2008
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753302.aspx

> User Name Mapping has changed—server functionality no longer exists, but client functionality is present. Services for NFS can still retrieve mappings from existing legacy User Name Mapping servers.

So you would need a w2003 server.

I haven't tried it in 2008, but the article implies you can use local accounts - if you select the AD option, does it proceed without a domain?

Comment: It just asks for a domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I may be reading into this too much, but it sounds like you are wanting to run VMs from an NFS share on a Windows 2008 server that has a larger amount of storage than your ESXi server does? I'd recommend against it for production.

You could always fire up Cygwin and run an NFS server on 2008!

http://www.csparks.com/CygwinNFS/index.xhtml

Have fun! Good luck!

Comment: The ESXi server has its own internal storage for running the VMs on, this is just for a nightly backup up the VMs, using ghettoVCB.